# Which "Display item" type is the code? (For changing color syntax highlighting)

Tags: syntax-highlighting, visual-studio-2015

I'm editing a C++ file in VS 2015 RC.  I'd like to change how something is colored.

If I go into Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors, there's a really long list of "Display items".

Is there a way to see what "Display item" type corresponds with whatever the cursor or mouse is pointing to in the editor, to avoid the guess-check-guess cycle?

Answer (score 0):

It's "Highlighted Reference". Took me a while to find it.

Comment: @user5540789, not sure if I'm confused or if we're talking about two different things. Highlighted Reference looks to me like it's the feature that highlights a clicked symbol and all other instances of the symbol, including declarations and references. What I was asking about is if there's a way to figure out for any text in the source code, what it's particular type is. Meaning, if I see something that is blue, and want to change it to green, but I don't know what type it is in Fonts and Colors Display Items, how do I change color, without looking through 100+ items and trying until it works